# Same vertical spacing for chapter and chapter*

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I use `\chapter*{}` in the `\frontmatter` and `\chapter{}` in the `\mainmatter`.

I use [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and the styling of the chapter headings is this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{book}
...
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\justifyheading}
  {\filleft\Large\textsc{\chaptertitlename}~\Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{0ex}\filleft}
```

**Question:** How do I get the chapter title to be at the same level? [See the problem in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq7HW.png), I want the titlerules to be at the same level (i.e. same distance from the top).

**Bonus-question:** How do I push the "Chapter 1" to the right so the number is hanging outside the margin?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to have two definitions: one for numbered chapters and the other one, for unnumbered chapters, using the `numberless` key. In the definition for unnumbered chapters, some `\phantom`s are used to hide the chapter name and the chapter number; for the bonus question, a `\rlap` will do the job:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\justifyheading}
  {\filleft\Large\textsc{\chaptertitlename}\rlap{~\Huge\thechapter}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\filleft}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\justifyheading}
  {\filleft\Large\textsc{\phantom{\chaptertitlename}}\rlap{~\Huge\phantom{\thechapter}}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\filleft}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\chapter*{Test Unnumbered Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With your current settings, you need to use a font allowing you bold-faced small caps, although I would suggest you to have only small caps (not boldfaced).

As **barbara beeton** has suggested, your current settings will result in the title being too close to the rule; adding some spacing would produce a better result:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\justifyheading}
  {\filleft\Large\textsc{\chaptertitlename}\rlap{~\Huge\thechapter}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vskip1ex\filleft}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\justifyheading}
  {\filleft\Large\textsc{\phantom{\chaptertitlename}}\rlap{~\Huge\phantom{\thechapter}}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vskip1ex\filleft}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\chapter*{Test Unnumbered Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a bit of separation between the rule and the title would look nicer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton True, but these are the OP's original settings. I will suggest increasing the separation in my answer.

Comment: aha!  i didn't look carefully at his code; i looked instead at the linked screenshot.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added the code to produce some spacing between the rule and the title.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I agree with @barbarabeeton, it looks nicer with a bit of separation :) I don't know why I had `\vspace{0ex}` in the posted code.